# Unable to export private and public keys under Mac

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a public and private key in one machine, I tried to export them under the name of  key.cer, I mean what other option is there besides .certificate extension.

Now I moved that key.cer which supposedly contain the private and public keys to another machine. but no luck, the two keys did not show up in the keychain of the new machine.

Answer (score 1):

That's because .cer is just the certificate. When exporting a certificate that includes a private key, you should stick with the default export option, which is a .p12 file.

Comment: OK, I did that. but when I drag that .p12 file into the keychain of the new system nothing happened.  It seems like its doing it but no effect. The key didn't show up in the new system

Answer (score 1):

You should only export your private key..

Comment: OK, I did that. but when I drag that .p12 file with private key into the keychain of the new system nothing happened.  It seems like its doing it but no effect. The key didn't show up in the new system

Comment: When you export your .p12 file, the system should ask you to put password in order to protect your .p12 file. On the new system, just double click on your .p12 file and it should ask your password.. Then you'll be allowed to use your certificate on your new system